# Dart Deserialization

Tags: flutter, dart, generics, serialization, types

I'm trying to write some deserialization code in Dart.  The type system is giving me grief.  My understanding is that this is [a](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1357) [common](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66996780/generic-deserialization-in-flutter-dart) [conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27135876/state-of-serialization-and-deserialization-of-json-in-dart).  I'm having trouble really believing that there's no workaround.  I think one way of boiling down the problem is that *if* the following worked:

```
List createListOf(Type t) {
  return <t>[];
}
```

*or* you could cast a `List<Object>` to an e.g. `List<String>` (as you can in Java, if you cast through Object first), then you could get deserialization to work (for at least any combination of preregistered types, assuming other generic objects behave analogously to `List`).  Specifically, the ability to construct something that can be cast to a generic of type `Foo<T>`, where `T` isn't known at compile time.  (Some of my objects, for instance, contain a `Map<String, Object>`, so anything complex that was serialized from that map will have trouble in deserialization.)

There's the `mirror` package, I hear, but [I hear it messes up your code optimization, significantly increases the size of your app, is deprecated/discouraged, and doesn't work in Flutter at all](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/44489).

Is there really no other workaround?  No really ugly string of casts, no obscure operators, no horrifying black magic dealing with pointers and dead cats?  (Like, that still at least works in *most* conditions.)  It just doesn't seem like it should be that big an ask.

Comment: Your fundamental problem is that you want your function to construct an arbitrary object with a *static* (known at compile-time) type based on a *runtime* argument.  That is impossible for arbitrary arguments.  The typical way to deal with deserialization (or to deal with wanting to use `dart:mirrors`) is to use code-generation.  If you want to serialize and deserialize JSON, please don't do it yourself and just use `package:json_serializable` or `package:built_value`.

Comment: @jamesdlin I mean, *I* don't care about the static typing of my constructed objects, personally.  I care about their runtime types, and about the runtime errors I get when I e.g. cast a deserialized list to a list field that DOES have a statically defined type.  Unfortunately, it appears I can't get an arbitrary runtime type without ALSO having the exact complete static type somewhere, as well.

Comment: You need to know the static type of the object you want to construct in order to invoke the appropriate constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast a List by casting the objects in it one by one:

```
objectList.map((object) => object as String).toList();
```

Comment: Yeah - unfortunately, you apparently still need a static type reference to e.g. `String` to do that, not just an instance of `Type`, which the `Map<String, Object>` I mentioned wouldn't be able to provide.  I guess whenever you pulled something from the map, you could do a bunch of complex checking and recursively cast any lists etc., but that's kindof horrible and moves deserialization code outside the place where deserialization happens.